# Aurelia-CLI issue

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to use the aurelia cli to create a new project
Here are the options I'm using.

```
Project Name: Test
Default Setup: 3 (custom) 
Module Loader: 3 (webPack)
Plaform: 2 (ASP.NET Core)
Transpiler: Babel
Template setup: Default
CSS Processor: 1 (None default)
Test Runner: 2 (Karma)
Integration Testing: 1 (protractor)
Code Editor: 1 (VS Code)
```

When its complete since I told it I was targeting ASP.NET Core I thought I would be able to do a dotnet run.
I can and it says the app is running and listening on port `5000`.

If I navigate to `http://localhost:5000` a page comes up and just shows `loading...`
If you look at the console you see that it cant find `app.js`, `vendor.css`, `vendor.js`

If you go looking for these files, they are nowhere to be found. Its looking for them in the dist folder but they do not exist.

Is this a bug in the cli using these options?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. I just tried the above steps and as described they didn't work because of .net stuff. I had to run `dotnet restore` then `dotnet build` then `dotnet run`. Once I did that, I could navigate to `localhost:5000` and the app loaded just fine. What version of .net core are you running? what version of aurelia-cli? etc.

Comment: I'm using the aurelia-cli 0.31.3

dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.0
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  cdcd1928c9

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.14393
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d